# Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'vehicle_details.batch_id' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql

I am getting an **Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'vehicle_details.batch_id' in 'on clause'** errror when running the following MySQL query.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

John

```
SELECT 
    supplier,
    vehicle_details.status,
    vehicle_details.batch_id,
    veh_id,
    fund_type,
    suppliers.supplier_name,
    reg_no,
    car_make.car_make,
    car_model,
    creation_date,
    stock_plan,
    money_received,
    hpi_registered,
    invoice_checked,
    details_checked,
    confirmation_received,
    log_mot_check
FROM
    vehicle_details,
    suppliers,
    car_make
LEFT JOIN batch
ON vehicle_details.batch_id = batch.batch_id
WHERE
    vehicle_details.supplier = suppliers.supplier_id
        AND vehicle_details.car_make = car_make.car_id
        AND vehicle_details.status like 's'
        AND vehicle_details.batch_id like '%'
        AND veh_id like '%'
        AND fund_type like '%'
        AND supplier like '%'
        AND reg_no like '%'
        AND car_id like '%'
        AND car_model like '%'
        AND creation_date like '%'
        AND stock_plan like '%'
        AND money_received like '%'
ORDER BY vehicle_details.batch_id DESC
```

Comment: Don't mix implicit and explicit join syntax

Comment: @juergend Hi Juergen, I am a SQL newbie and don't know what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use only the explicit join syntax

```
SELECT 
    supplier,
    vehicle_details.status,
    vehicle_details.batch_id,
    veh_id,
    fund_type,
    suppliers.supplier_name,
    reg_no,
    car_make.car_make,
    car_model,
    creation_date,
    stock_plan,
    money_received,
    hpi_registered,
    invoice_checked,
    details_checked,
    confirmation_received,
    log_mot_check
FROM
    vehicle_details
INNER JOIN suppliers ON vehicle_details.supplier = suppliers.supplier_id
INNER JOIN car_make ON vehicle_details.car_make = car_make.car_id
LEFT JOIN batch ON vehicle_details.batch_id = batch.batch_id
WHERE   vehicle_details.status like 's'
        AND (vehicle_details.batch_id is null or vehicle_details.batch_id like '%')
        AND veh_id like '%'
        AND fund_type like '%'
        AND supplier like '%'
        AND reg_no like '%'
        AND car_id like '%'
        AND car_model like '%'
        AND creation_date like '%'
        AND stock_plan like '%'
        AND money_received like '%'
ORDER BY vehicle_details.batch_id DESC
```

You join here implicit

```
FROM
vehicle_details,
suppliers,
car_make
```

and there explicit

```
LEFT JOIN batch ON vehicle_details.batch_id = batch.batch_id
```

Comment: The problem I have is now is that records are not not returned if they have a NULL value in  vehicle_details.batch_id. Any ideas on how I can get around this?